# Нужна ли запятая после "однако"?

Tags: пунктуация

Однако появились и новые проблемы...

Answer (score 1):

Слово "однако", стоящее в начале предложения, является противительным союзом, а не вводным словом, поэтому здесь запятая не нужна.

Comment: А разве это слово может быть вводным?

Comment: Может, если стоит в середине или в конце предложения: Я, однако, в этом уверен. Я в этом уверен, однако.